# Join condition in Oracle query

Tags: oracle, left-join, inner-join

I have following query which update the coulmn "tmp_activation_date" of rec_tmprecord table with max of actdate according to the conditions mentioned in query.

```
MERGE INTO rec_tmprecord
   USING (SELECT   rec.ID, MAX (act.actdate) AS tmpactivation_date
              FROM rec_tmprecord rec INNER JOIN tmp_asset asset
                   ON asset.serial = rec.serialtemp 
                   and upper (replace (asset.prodname, 'Ajink ')) = upper (replace (rec.prodnametemp, 'Ajink '))
                   and NVL(asset.release,'NF') = NVL(rec.tmprelease ,'NF')
                   and rec.serialtemp != 'aaa-aaaaaaaa'                   
                   LEFT JOIN tmp_acti_hist act
                   ON asset.tmp_id = act.tmp_row_id
             WHERE rec.cust_id = 234567
          GROUP BY rec.cust_id,asset.serial,rec.ID) new_values
   ON (rec_tmprecord.ID = new_values.ID)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
         SET tmp_activation_date = new_values.tmpactivation_date
      ;
```

But,When i analyzed the data of table "rec_tmprecord",i found that there are some null or blank values present in the "prodnametemp" column of "rec_tmprecord" table.But,column "prodname" of the table "tmp_asset" does not contain any null or blank values. 
So,my join condition will fail at "upper (replace (asset.prodname, 'Ajink ')) = upper (replace (rec.prodnametemp, 'Ajink '))" condition and as a result  "tmp_activation_date" of rec_tmprecord table will be updated with null value or blank value.

what my requirement is if "prodnametemp" is having null value and "prodname" contains some value  then also "tmpactivation_date" will get calculated on the basis of other conditions mentioned in the query.
Anyhelp on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `tmp_activation_date` won't be updated to `null` in that scenario; you won't have a row for that in the `using` section - the join condition fails, so there will be nothing to match on?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version. I modified the join as follows:

```
upper (replace (asset.prodname, 'Ajink ')) = NVL(upper (replace (rec.prodnametemp, 'Ajink ')), upper (replace (asset.prodname, 'Ajink ')))
```

**EDIT**:
The join condition has been compressed, thanks to Alex Poole's suggestion.

Basically, if is NULL, then that condition would return TRUE, because then asset.prodname = asset.prodname.

```
MERGE INTO rec_tmprecord
   USING (SELECT   rec.ID, MAX (act.actdate) AS tmpactivation_date
              FROM rec_tmprecord rec INNER JOIN tmp_asset asset
                   ON asset.serial = rec.serialtemp 
                   and upper (replace (asset.prodname, 'Ajink ')) = upper (replace (NVL (rec.prodnametemp, asset.prodname), 'Ajink '))
                   and NVL(asset.release,'NF') = NVL(rec.tmprelease ,'NF')
                   and rec.serialtemp != 'aaa-aaaaaaaa'                   
                   LEFT JOIN tmp_acti_hist act
                   ON asset.tmp_id = act.tmp_row_id
             WHERE rec.cust_id = 234567
          GROUP BY rec.cust_id,asset.serial,rec.ID) new_values
   ON (rec_tmprecord.ID = new_values.ID)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
         SET tmp_activation_date = new_values.tmpactivation_date
      ;
```

Comment: Saved me some typing... but for brevity I'd have put the `NVL` inside the `replace` on the right-hand side: `= upper(replace(nvl(rec.prodnametemp,asset.prodname), 'Ajink '))`. Functionally the same though!